# ClassCastException using Iterables from Guava

Tags: java, android, guava

I am trying to use the Iterables class to filter an ArrayList, but when I try to cast the result back to the original type I get a ClassCastException at runtime.

```
// domains is an ArrayList<Domain> which is defined earlier in the class
Iterable<Domain> temp = Iterables.filter(domains, new Predicate<Domain>() {
    public boolean apply(Domain input) {
        if (input.getName().toLowerCase().contains(filter.toString().toLowerCase())) {
            return true ;
        } else {
            return false;
        }
    }
}) ;
ArrayList<Domain> filteredDomains = (ArrayList<Domain>) temp ; // Error occurs here
```

To be complete, I am trying to use this in an Android application with a target of 1.6.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

`temp` is **not an `ArrayList<Domain>`**. It is an `Iterable<Domain>`.

If you **absolutely** *need* an `ArrayList<Domain>` (or a `List<Domain>` in general), then you need to take a slightly different approach.

First, use [`Collections2.filter()`](http://guava-libraries.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/javadoc/com/google/common/collect/Collections2.html#filter%28java.util.Collection,%20com.google.common.base.Predicate%29) instead of [`Iterables.filter()`](http://guava-libraries.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/javadoc/com/google/common/collect/Iterables.html#filter%28java.lang.Iterable,%20com.google.common.base.Predicate%29): to produce `temp` and then create a new `ArrayList` from the resulting `Collection`:

```
Collection<Domain> temp = Collections2.filter(domains, myPredicate) ;
List<Domain> filteredDomains = new ArrayList<Domain>(temp);
```

But you should really think if you *need* a `List` or `ArrayList` and if a `Collection` is not enough for what you want. If an `Iterable` is sufficient (for example if you only iterate over the content), then you can even keep using `Iterables.filter()`.

Comment: This won't compile.  temp is not a collection

Answer (score 0):

Temp is an Iterable not an ArrayList.  Further more an ArrayList is an Iterable but not vice versa.  What if you had

```
Iterable<?> iterable = new HashSet<?>();
```

You can see why a class cast exception would happen here.

To create an ArrayList from the Iterable you would have to iterate over the iterable itself and add to a new ArrayList

```
List<Domain> filteredDomains = new ArrayList<Domain>();

for(Iterator<Domain> i = temp.iterator(); i.hasNext();){
  filteredDomains.add(i.next());
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The real return type is an anonymous class that extends `IterableWithToString` - and we cannot cast *that* type to `ArrayList`.

[Here's the implementation on grepcode](http://grepcode.com/file/repo1.maven.org/maven2/com.google.guava/guava/r09/com/google/common/collect/Iterables.java).

Comment: OK, that makes sense, but how can I determine the number of elements in an `Iterable` without having to loop through the entire collection?

Comment: `Iterables.size(temp)`  (see http://guava-libraries.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/javadoc/com/google/common/collect/Iterables.html#size(java.lang.Iterable))

Comment: @Ray: `Iterables.size` does loop through the `Iterable` unless it's a `Collection`, though.

Comment: Indeed; if infosec812 is trying to avoid a performance issue, this would not be the solution. If it's only a matter of wanting a one-line way to get the size, this `Iterables.size` will do it. Personally I would use `Collections2.filter`